# ArrivalEvent.java:6: error: constructor Event in class Event cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java

I can't seem to find the error. I am having a compile-time issue. I can't compile it as it is giving me an error which I can resolved.

```
  1 class ArrivalEvent extends Event {
  2     Counter counterList[];
  3     Customer currentCustomer;
  4     Counter currentCounter;
  5
  6     public ArrivalEvent(Counter[] counterList, Customer currentCustomer){
  7         this.counterList = counterList;
  8         this.currentCustomer = currentCustomer;
  9     }
}
```

Comment: When creating a child constructor, there's an implicit call to `super()`, which is the constructor of the base class. It seems the base class `Event` doesn't have a default constructor without parameters. Please post the `Event` class as well

Comment: Yup, thanks! I got it!